# Ansible item in list explicitly

Tags: ansible, jinja2, devops, ansible-2.x

```
item_list: [data, database, proddata]
```

I'm trying to do a conditional `when: item.name in item_list`

How do I make the when clause explicit so that if my list of items I'm looping thru are [data] only, that 'database' and 'proddata' don't pass the condition as true? I want only EXACT spelling to pass.

Example

```
---

- name: Explicit example
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    source_list: 
      - name: proddata
      - name: data
      - name: other
    dest_list1: [this, thing]
    dest_list2: [database, proddata]
    final_list: '{{ dest_list1 | union(dest_list2) | join(",") }}'

  tasks:
  - name: test
    debug:
      msg: '{{ item.name }}'
    with_items: 
      - '{{ source_list }}'
    when: item.name in final_list
```

As you can see, `data` is not in `final_list` but it shows up true. I believe because *data* is contained in prod*data* and *data*base. I wish to do `when: item.name == (item.name in final_list)` if possible. I'm just not sure which filter I need.

Comment: Can you give us examples? Chances are, you'll need `filter()` for this, but the question is very unclear.

Comment: Woops! My apologies. I though I was looking at the python tags. Still, I can't imagine this is very clear to others.

Comment: What type are `data` etc of?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Please see my example

Comment: @Goodies can you provide any insight to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would work if your `final_list` was a list and not a string with comma separated values.

So if your var definition was like this:

```
final_list: '{{ dest_list1 | union(dest_list2) }}'
```

the condition

```
when: item.name in final_list
```

would be working.

But I assume you have it stored as a string for a reason because you use it somewhere else. If that's the case and you can not change it (you could do the `join` where you need it as a string) you can simply split it in your condition:

```
when: item.name in final_list.split(",")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @udondan! '| join(",")' was my issue - removing it worked. I'd vote up this answer but SO won't let me :-\